# The scrolltop of page is changed when I hide the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

The `scrolltop` of page is changed when I move scroll a little and hide element.
(if `scrolltop` is 0, it doesn't happen). Condition is
property of the element's parents is `{position: absolute; bottom:0; right: 0}` and I move scroll of page.

Then the `scrolltop` move to bottom.

Why it happen?

```js
$('button.close').on('click', function(){
  $('.layer-content').css({display: 'none'})
});

$('button.show').on('click', function(){
  $('.layer-content').show()
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  position:relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: #d0d0d0;
}
.parent .layer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
.parent .layer button {
  position: absoulte;
  top: 0;
  right: 0
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="show">show</button>
  <div class="layer">
    <div class="layer-content">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint dolore necessitatibus cupiditate maiores, optio aut. A nisi possimus voluptate velit, voluptates repellendus dolorum, totam quia fuga neque, provident vel tempore?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, ex reprehenderit voluptatem velit totam, modi quae saepe ipsum tempora, vero labore. Minima voluptatem repudiandae accusantium fugiat veniam recusandae facere beatae.
</div>
```

Comment: open developer tools and watch the CSS change as you scroll and call different jQuery functions.  do that for a good hour or two and you'll get some ideas.

Comment: i figure out height of .layer element became 0 when close button is clicked.
but i think it is not relevant to scrolltop of page, because .parent has height of 300px.
i still don't understand why scrolltop is changed.